# Flutter Audio_service click function not triggered for iOS

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I am trying to do a custom action for the next and previous clicks in my headset. The way to do it is by using the click() based on the documentation. I used it and it is working perfectly for Android, but iOS it is not getting triggered at all. Everything else is working.

That's the click code:

```
  Future<void> click([MediaButton button = MediaButton.media]) async {
    switch (button) {
      case MediaButton.media:
        if (playbackState.valueOrNull?.playing == true) {
          await pause();
        } else {
          await play();
        }
        break;
      case MediaButton.next:
        await fastForward();
        break;
      case MediaButton.previous:
        await rewind();
        break;
    }
  }
```

Yet, when I click on next or previous in my headset it goes to next/previous item in the queue instead of rewinding/fastforwarding